# Build error in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, shader

Help me with the error `Source1.cpp(128): error C3861: 'InitShader': identifier not found` when I have 2 files and one is `InitShader.cpp`. Both files compile. I believe that it is some setting in Visual Studio to make the one file find the other, since the InitShader is referenced by the other source file. The project looks like this in VS 2012

[image]

The code is

```
#include "Angel.h"

namespace Angel {

// Create a NULL-terminated string by reading the provided file
static char*
readShaderSource(const char* shaderFile)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(shaderFile, "r");

    if ( fp == NULL ) { return NULL; }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    char* buf = new char[size + 1];
    fread(buf, 1, size, fp);

    buf[size] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

    return buf;
}


// Create a GLSL program object from vertex and fragment shader files
GLuint
InitShader(const char* vShaderFile, const char* fShaderFile)
{
    struct Shader {
    const char*  filename;
    GLenum       type;
    GLchar*      source;
    }  shaders[2] = {
    { vShaderFile, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, NULL },
    { fShaderFile, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, NULL }
    };

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();


    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
    Shader& s = shaders[i];
    s.source = readShaderSource( s.filename );
    if ( shaders[i].source == NULL ) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read " << s.filename << std::endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    GLuint shader = glCreateShader( s.type );

    glShaderSource( shader, 1, (const GLchar**) &s.source, NULL );
    glCompileShader( shader );

    GLint  compiled;
    glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled );
    if ( !compiled ) {
        std::cerr << s.filename << " failed to compile:" << std::endl;
        GLint  logSize;
        glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize );
        char* logMsg = new char[logSize];
        glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, logSize, NULL, logMsg );
        std::cerr << logMsg << std::endl;
        delete [] logMsg;

        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    delete [] s.source;

    glAttachShader( program, shader );
    }

    /* link  and error check */
    glLinkProgram(program);

    GLint  linked;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked );
    if ( !linked ) {
    std::cerr << "Shader program failed to link" << std::endl;
    GLint  logSize;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize);
    char* logMsg = new char[logSize];
    glGetProgramInfoLog( program, logSize, NULL, logMsg );
    std::cerr << logMsg << std::endl;
    delete [] logMsg;

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    /* use program object */
    glUseProgram(program);

    return program;
}

}  // Close namespace Angel block
```

Comment: You should declare it in a header and include that in both files.

Comment: Sounds like a missing header include, as mentioned. We'll need a code snippet to provide more information, though.

Comment: Sounds like a circular include to me...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Since my question was so brief I've now updated it with more info that you may have a look at.

Comment: C doesn't have namespaces.

Comment: @genpfault And C doesn't have threads or does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error sounds like it's coming from Source1.cpp not being communicating properly with InitShader.cpp

Since there doesn't appear to be a InitShader.h, I'm assuming you're trying to #include  in Source1.cpp, which probably is where the error comes in, since it's expecting a header file.

I'd say try moving all your function definition from InitShader.cpp over to an InitShader.h file, and try including that in Source1.cpp. This is my best guess without seeing the actual code in Source1.cpp.

---

Alternate idea:

It appears that you're providing the function body in InitShader.cpp for the function prototypes I assume in Angel.h. Are you declaring functions in Angel.h that you then define in InitShader.cpp? If so, I'd highly recomend creating an Angel.cpp file and defining the Angel functions there instead. It would be much cleaner, and I have a hunch that it might end up being the problem you're facing.

Comment: You're right, I've changed it to a `InitShader.h` and then it's working. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! You really might want to think about creating an Angel.cpp file though, and moving the Angel function definitions over there. Not strictly necessary, and might not make sense with the rest of your code (the parts I haven’t seen), but in general having .h and .cpp files having the same name really makes things a lot clearer and more organized.